# C++ code translation in VB6

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, vb6, call

I've a C dll and I want to use it in vb6, here is the C syntax:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
typedef long long INT64T;
#else
typedef __int64 INT64T;
#endif

int Init(int opts, void *key, INT64T offs);
```

I've converted it to VB6:

```
Public Declare Function Init Lib "x.dll" (ByVal opts As Integer, ByVal key As Long, ByVal offs As Currency)
```

and call it:

```
Init 0, 0, 0
```

some part of the function is executed and the I've got this error:

> Bad DLL calling convention

would you please kindly let me know what is the problem? The dll is from  third-party dll so I don't know anything more about it,

Comment: int = vb6 Long (32 bits), short = Integer (16 bits). make sure you compile for 32 bit OS target, if you compile for 64 bit, pointer size is 64 bits

Comment: VB6 cannot be compiled to 64-bit so if the DLL is 64-bit, it can't be used from VB6

Comment: also I don't think the Currency thing will work...

Answer (score 0):

For 64 bit you should use:

```
Type ULARGE_INTEGER
  LowPart As Long
  HighPart As Long
End Type
```

and your declaration should be like this:

```
Public Declare Function Init Lib "x.dll" (ByVal opts As Long, ByVal key As Long, ByVal offs As ULARGE_INTEGER)

Public Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" (ByVal Destination As Long, ByVal Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)
```

Now to the conversions:

After you get the `ULARGE_INTEGER` you can translate it to `Currency` like this:

```
' Copy int64 into the Currency data type
Dim curr as Currency
Dim int64 as ULARGE_INTEGER

' Copy ULARGE_INTEGER into the Currency data type
CopyMemory curr, int64, 8

' Multiply by 10000 to move Visual Basic decimal point to the end of the actual number
curr = curr * 10000
```

to traverse back to `ULARGE_INTEGER` from `Currency`:

```
Dim curr as Currency
Dim int64 as ULARGE_INTEGER

' Devide by 10000 to move Visual Basic decimal point to original position
curr = curr * 0.00001       

' Copy Currency into the ULARGE_INTEGER data type
CopyMemory int64, curr, 8
```

Comment: Thx SHR, but I've still got "Bad DLL calling convention" Using ULARGE_INTEGER